# Detecting a large square region of same color in a video

Tags: image, image-processing, video, geometry, video-processing

Imagine there is a video and in a video there is a "pixelated" region where say region of 100×100 pixels is occupied by smaller 25×25 squares of the same color. Something like this but within a video (which may contain any of the colors of the edge squares, i.e. black, red, blue, etc background):

[image: Example image]

I need to find those individual regions (which are always square) to outline the entire region occupied by these squares. The full region does not have to be square or be of any particular shape, so there could be 5 "large-pixels" in a cross shape.

I am seeking for an algorithm to do that, preferably stand alone (without external libraries). I have no preference of the language (anything from Python to Java or Lisp to C++).

P.S. The video can have any dimensions, for example 500×600 pixels or 1920×1080, but the size of the single "large-pixel" will be relative to the size of the video, so in other words 500×600 may have 25-high and 1920×1080 may be 100-high.

P.S.S. Issue is that neighboring "large-pixels" may be of the same color and they should be detected as individual squares.

Comment: Are these video frames YUV or RGB (or is it negotiable)? Will the blocks always be exactly the same color or approximate?

Comment: @MultimediaMike Frames can be of any format (encoded with any popular codec). Blocks are always square and they always contain exactly same color over the entire block in original video. This means if video is overcompressed, colors may go off, but it is not a big concern, as I expect videos with barely any compression.